# date_parser failing with: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'month'

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, int, date-parsing

I realize that this error is usually due to a float or a decimal being passed through to the `int()` function; however, I do not understand how it is applying to my program now. I am using a function called `dateparse` to parse dates from generic file formats in order to make csv files that follow a date_time format. I have the following code:

```
names=dates['Year','Month','Day','Hour','Minute',\
'T2 (WRF)', 'TSK (WRF)', 'LH (WRF)','HS (WRF)', 'Q2 (WRF)',\
'U10 (WRF)','V10 (WRF)','PSFC (WRF)','ZNT (WRF)','SWDOWN (WRF)','RAINNC (WRF)']

def dateparse(Y, m, d, H, M):
    a = pd.datetime(int(Y), int(m), int(d), int(H), int(M))
    return(a)

df=pd.read_csv(filein,delim_whitespace=True,\
header=None, names=names, parse_dates={'date_time': dates},\
date_parser=dateparse, index_col='date_time')
df.to_csv(fileout+'.csv', index=True)
```

my data looks like this, all formatted the same:

```
2014 06 28 12 00 298.406 296.388 8.60505e-05 -11.8442 0.00890335 -0.125414 -0.681333 96967.9 0.79537 0 0
2014 06 28 13 00 298.6 296.854 9.5607e-05 -10.5284 0.00823525 -1.04711 -0.317631 97030 0.79537 19.3502 0
2014 06 28 14 00 301.66 303.488 0.000109433 30.6269 0.00898107 0.000669297 -1.06901 97086.2 0.79537 213.257 0
2014 06 28 15 00 302.186 307.853 0.000169239 128.347 0.00898755 0.993213 -1.16031 97081.7 0.79537 433.372 0
2014 06 28 16 00 303.145 312.31 0.000230749 219.192 0.00874303 0.644703 -0.80952 97137.6 0.79537 639.32 0
```

So the headers should be Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minutes. All of these are integers and I do not understand why this is throwing back an error. I have had this program work before with very similar data, with the same format for the time.

Answer (score 0):

zero leading strings can't be converted to `int`, if you do the following then it will work:

```
In [36]:

import io
t="""2014 06 28 12 00 298.406 296.388 8.60505e-05 -11.8442 0.00890335 -0.125414 -0.681333 96967.9 0.79537 0 0
2014 06 28 13 00 298.6 296.854 9.5607e-05 -10.5284 0.00823525 -1.04711 -0.317631 97030 0.79537 19.3502 0
2014 06 28 14 00 301.66 303.488 0.000109433 30.6269 0.00898107 0.000669297 -1.06901 97086.2 0.79537 213.257 0
2014 06 28 15 00 302.186 307.853 0.000169239 128.347 0.00898755 0.993213 -1.16031 97081.7 0.79537 433.372 0
2014 06 28 16 00 303.145 312.31 0.000230749 219.192 0.00874303 0.644703 -0.80952 97137.6 0.79537 639.32 0"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=[['Year','Month','Day','Hour','Minute']], names = ['Year','Month','Day','Hour','Minute',\
'T2 (WRF)', 'TSK (WRF)', 'LH (WRF)','HS (WRF)', 'Q2 (WRF)',\
'U10 (WRF)','V10 (WRF)','PSFC (WRF)','ZNT (WRF)','SWDOWN (WRF)','RAINNC (WRF)'])
df

Out[36]:
  Year_Month_Day_Hour_Minute  T2 (WRF)  TSK (WRF)  LH (WRF)  HS (WRF)  \
0           2014 06 28 12 00   298.406    296.388  0.000086  -11.8442   
1           2014 06 28 13 00   298.600    296.854  0.000096  -10.5284   
2           2014 06 28 14 00   301.660    303.488  0.000109   30.6269   
3           2014 06 28 15 00   302.186    307.853  0.000169  128.3470   
4           2014 06 28 16 00   303.145    312.310  0.000231  219.1920   

   Q2 (WRF)  U10 (WRF)  V10 (WRF)  PSFC (WRF)  ZNT (WRF)  SWDOWN (WRF)  \
0  0.008903  -0.125414  -0.681333     96967.9    0.79537        0.0000   
1  0.008235  -1.047110  -0.317631     97030.0    0.79537       19.3502   
2  0.008981   0.000669  -1.069010     97086.2    0.79537      213.2570   
3  0.008988   0.993213  -1.160310     97081.7    0.79537      433.3720   
4  0.008743   0.644703  -0.809520     97137.6    0.79537      639.3200   

   RAINNC (WRF)  
0             0  
1             0  
2             0  
3             0  
4             0  
In [39]:
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year_Month_Day_Hour_Minute'], format='%Y %m %d %H %M' )
df

Out[39]:
  Year_Month_Day_Hour_Minute  T2 (WRF)  TSK (WRF)  LH (WRF)  HS (WRF)  \
0           2014 06 28 12 00   298.406    296.388  0.000086  -11.8442   
1           2014 06 28 13 00   298.600    296.854  0.000096  -10.5284   
2           2014 06 28 14 00   301.660    303.488  0.000109   30.6269   
3           2014 06 28 15 00   302.186    307.853  0.000169  128.3470   
4           2014 06 28 16 00   303.145    312.310  0.000231  219.1920   

   Q2 (WRF)  U10 (WRF)  V10 (WRF)  PSFC (WRF)  ZNT (WRF)  SWDOWN (WRF)  \
0  0.008903  -0.125414  -0.681333     96967.9    0.79537        0.0000   
1  0.008235  -1.047110  -0.317631     97030.0    0.79537       19.3502   
2  0.008981   0.000669  -1.069010     97086.2    0.79537      213.2570   
3  0.008988   0.993213  -1.160310     97081.7    0.79537      433.3720   
4  0.008743   0.644703  -0.809520     97137.6    0.79537      639.3200   

   RAINNC (WRF)                Date  
0             0 2014-06-28 12:00:00  
1             0 2014-06-28 13:00:00  
2             0 2014-06-28 14:00:00  
3             0 2014-06-28 15:00:00  
4             0 2014-06-28 16:00:00
```

So here I treat the year month day hour and minute as a single column, I then call `to_datetime` and pass `format = '%Y %m %d %H %M'`, you can see that this parses correctly:

```
In [40]:

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 13 columns):
Year_Month_Day_Hour_Minute    5 non-null object
T2 (WRF)                      5 non-null float64
TSK (WRF)                     5 non-null float64
LH (WRF)                      5 non-null float64
HS (WRF)                      5 non-null float64
Q2 (WRF)                      5 non-null float64
U10 (WRF)                     5 non-null float64
V10 (WRF)                     5 non-null float64
PSFC (WRF)                    5 non-null float64
ZNT (WRF)                     5 non-null float64
SWDOWN (WRF)                  5 non-null float64
RAINNC (WRF)                  5 non-null int64
Date                          5 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(10), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 600.0+ bytes
```

Comment: This data is coming from a file, so I basically just make `t=file.readlines()`?

Comment: You should be able to use `pandas.read_csv` to read this in as before